# Make button style same in overall application

Tags: wpf, button

i am develop the WPF window application.I am new to WPF . I want to use same button style in overall application.  I know we need to write style in app.xaml. I can code for simple button But I want to set the image for this button

Please suggest any link / sample code for app.xaml file so it is applicable for overall application

Comment: you want to set the same image on ALL buttons? or diff image on diff buttons?

Answer (score 0):

For that you must override the general button template. in your App.Xaml (or any more adequate location) define the following:

```
<Application.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
                        <Border>
                        <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="../Resources/Images/foo.png"></Image>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>                            
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This Style has no key and is therefor applied to all Button instances. Note that you must set an explicit Type, you can't do that for, say, ButtonBase.

Be advised that this removes the button chrome (replaces it with a simple border), if you want to keep the original chrome get a grip on the original button template first and modify it accordingly (wrap a Grid or DockPanel around the ContentPresenter and add the Image).

You can get the original template using tools like "WPF Control Template Viewer" or Expression Blend.

Comment: Or one could get the style from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html) for how to make a `ControlTemplate` for a button... this example does not have an `<Image>` but, you should be able to easily modify the example source to add one... since you want to use the same image in every button this is a relativly simple addition and I'm leaving it for you as a learning exercise.  It also might be useful for you to look at [this MSDN article](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx&ei=5TUNT7DSLMamiQLwrqzyCA&usg=AFQjCNFfaTt2DS5qBKkBfxmaIopcx3DZvg&sig2=NSc9QqvDhhhWwvfey_nXmw) on using `ControlTemplates`